# C pointer problem!

Tags: c

Why does the following C code does not **ouput 10**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void get_length(char s[]);
int main( ) 
{
char buff[128];
printf("\nEnter buffer data: ");
scanf("%s",buff);
get_length(buff);
}

void get_length(char *s){
    int count;  
for(count = 0 ; *s != '\0' ; s++)
    count++;
printf("count = %d\n",count);
}
```

The **input is** I am Rohit
The **output is**
count = 432
Can anyone please explain that.

Comment: You need to put field limit widths on your string otherwise it can crash with huge input data (e.g. %20s instead of %s)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to have a `5` instead of a `%` in your `scanf` format string. (Perhaps your keyboard's shift key needs cleaning.)

That means that `scanf` isn't actually reading anything into your buffer. Your code doesn't check the return value from `scanf` (it should!) and therefore never notices that it failed. So you're then trying to calculate the length of ... a buffer full of uninitialized junk. It could give you 432, or 0, or anything else at all.

[EDITED to add:] ... Oh. And even if you fix that, it still won't work because *`scanf` will stop reading when it sees a whitespace character*, including a newline, and therefore the `\n` your `get_length` function is looking for will not be in the buffer.

Incidentally, do you know about the `strlen` function in the C standard library?

Comment: The % also doesn't make a difference.That's a mistake I changed it.

Comment: You changed what? The code here still says `scanf("5s",buff);`. Do you get the same wrong result if you make it say `scanf("%s",buff);`? (If you change it to say `"%5s"` then it'll probably fail for a different reason: with your test input the buffer will contain `I am ` and then a terminating zero-character, and then whatever garbage was in `buff` before ... and no newline, which is what your `get_length` function is looking for.)

Comment: D'oh, it will indeed fail even without the 5, because the newline will never be put into the buffer, because it's a whitespace character. Answer amended appropriately.

Comment: after changing the '\n' to a '\0' and changing the '5s' to '%s'(though all these were mistakes ,they were not done intentionally,becuase in my keyboard % = shift + 5) ,the ouput is "count =1"

Comment: 1 is the correct answer, because `scanf` reads up to the next whitespace character it sees. The length of the string "I" is indeed 1. If you want to read in the whole line, you should use `fgets` or something of the sort.

Answer (score 3):

I think you meant `%s`, not `5s`.

BTW, value-initialising your array (`char buff[128] = {}`) will prevent your array from being unbounded (`count = 432` is arbitrary for you).

You should then check for `*s != '\0'`, not `\n`, in `get_length` — C-style strings are bounded by the NULL character (`\0`), not newlines, regardless that you took the data from user input. The newline is lost from that input.

Comment: The % also doesn't make a difference.That's a mistake I changed it.

Comment: @user567797: Your real problem is in my last paragraph. Did you read it?

Answer (score 1):

The `scanf` call is failing because you have used an invalid format. If you want a string of length 5, then the format should be `"%5s"` instead of `"5s"`, or just `"%s"` if the five is a complete typo. So, the character buffer is uninitialized and you are getting the number of bytes before the first random `'\n'` character is encountered on the stack. Also, `scanf` ignores newline characters. So, your `get_length` function will never work as expected.

Comment: Indeed. Except he's not even scanning for `NULL`, but for newlines. Amaze.

Comment: I bet the 5 wasn't intended to be a length. On most keyboards `%` = shift-`5`... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think that scanf is reading your string in and setting the last char to '\0', but you are searching for '\n', which I don't think is implicit in the scanf implementation.

That is, check for '\0' instead of '\n'.